# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) Error Copy file from Asset to SdCard

Tags: android

I copy file from Asset folder in eclipse into Sdcard Genymotion Virtual Device, but i got error :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) .

Please help me 
P/s : I  was added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Manifest file .
This is my code

```
AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/tesseract/tessdata", lang + ".traineddata");
    if (!(file.exists())) {
        try {
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + lang
                    + ".traineddata");
            String sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/tesseract/tessdata";
            File outFile = new File(sdCardPath + "/", lang + ".traineddata");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + lang
                    + ".traineddata", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you working on Android 6.0? If Yes then you need to give run-time permission or that

Comment: yes I working on Android 6.0 .

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/tesseract/tessdata", lang + ".traineddata");
    if (!(file.exists())) {
        try {
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + lang
                    + ".traineddata");
            String sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/tesseract/tessdata";
            new File(sdCardPath).mkdirs();
            File outFile = new File(sdCardPath + "/", lang + ".traineddata");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + lang
                    + ".traineddata", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution working perfectly. Thank you so much Sabish.M